# Using templateUrl within template in angular2

Tags: html, css, angular, angular2-template

I've just started learning Angular2 and stuck at a point wherein I need to combine 2 components.

Here's my app.component.ts

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
     selector: 'app-root',
     template: './app.component.html <app-home></app-home>',
     styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      mylogo = 'ABC Engineering';
      headlist = ["Home", "About", "Portfolio", "Pricing", "Contact"];
      technology = ["HTML", "CSS", "JavaScript", "jQuery", "AngularJS",    "PHP"];
    }
```

Here's my app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    AboutComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],

  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

It gives the output as shown in the image. 
[image: Output]

It is not showing the output of app.component.html! But it does show the content from 'home.component.html'.
How do I fix it to show the content from 'app.component.html'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either use

```
   @Component({
     selector: 'app-root',
     templateUrl: './app.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
```

or

```
   @Component({
     selector: 'app-root',
     template: '<app-home></app-home>',
     styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
```

but not combine or mix both within a single component.

Comment: How do I join the 2 components in that case? I mean how do I join the app.component.html with home.component.html followed by about.component.html ?

Comment: Create a component containing that HTML and add its tag that matches it's selector to the other compinents template. There are great tutorials at http://angular.io

Comment: Oh now I get that! Thank you :)